Can't Free Space on Boot Drive
I have a MacBook Pro 16" 2019 model with a 4TB SSD internal drive. I am running out of space (VMs and video projects) and even though I moved these VMs and video projects to an external drive, deleted them from internal drive and emptied recycle bin, the space is not freed.
How do I reclaim this space?
Thank you.

What OS and is it APFS with snapshots? Disk utility and about this Mac have those details. Making a new Time Machine backup manually to external disk after deleting big files is usually a good way to start reclaiming high tide snapshots kept locally, but that’s just a hunch to what you’ve got going on.

You were probably backing up those large files with Time Machine, and they’re still in the local backups. Eventually they’ll be deleted, but you can delete all local backups immediately by running this command in a shell:
sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots


Thank you. That would make sense. I ran the command as entered and got: disablelocal: Unrecognized verb.

I corrected my answer.
